# How to access objects if we knew its one variable or parameter?

Tags: java

I have a class called `Plants` which has a constructor with 3 parameters( id , name , tiredness level).

I am getting the id of the plant then I would need its tiredness level.

I want to do something like `tirednessMap[a][b]=tirednessMap[a][b]+getLevel(3);` 
 where here 3 is the id of the plant.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ftm {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Plants artichoke = new Plants(1,"artichoke",6);
    Plants tomato = new Plants(2,"tomato",4); 
    Plants wheat = new Plants(3,"wheat", 2);
    Plants corn = new Plants(4,"corn", 3);
    Plants potato = new Plants(5,"potato", 1);
    System.out.println("Size X and Size Y");
    Scanner size= new Scanner(System.in);
    int szx=size.nextInt();
    int szy=size.nextInt();
    while (szx>40 || szy>40) {
        System.out.println("You can't enter a value bigger than 40!");
        szx= size.nextInt();
        szy= size.nextInt();
        }
    int tirednessMap[][]=new int[szx][szy];
    Scanner pinfo= new Scanner(System.in);
    int year= pinfo.nextInt();
    int numberOfPlants = pinfo.nextInt();
    int aydiz[]= new int[5];
    for (int i=0;i<numberOfPlants;i++) 
        aydiz[i]= pinfo.nextInt();

        }
    System.out.println();
    int x1= pinfo.nextInt();
    int y1= pinfo.nextInt();
    int x2= pinfo.nextInt();
    int y2= pinfo.nextInt();

    for (int i=0;i<numberOfPlants;i++) {    
        for(int a=x1;a<=x2;a++) {
            for(int b=y1;b<=y2;b++) {
                tirednessMap[a][b]=tirednessMap[a][b]+Plants.Level(aydiz[i]);

            }
        }


    }}
```

(This is another class file called Plants)

```
public class Plants {
   public int plant_id;
   public String plant_name;
   public int tiredness_level;
    public Plants(int id,String n, int l ) { 

            this.plant_id=id;
     this.plant_name=n;
     this.tiredness_level=l;
   }

public int getID() {
     return this.plant_id;
   }
   public String getName() {
     return this.plant_name;
  }
   public int getLevel() {
    return this.tiredness_level;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save your `Plants` objects somewhere and search/access the right `Plants` object based on the id. One of the many solutions is something like this:

```
List<Plants> allPlants = new ArrayList<Plants>();
allPlants.add(artichoke);
allPlants.add(tomato);
...
```

Then you define a method which expects this list and an "id" argument to identify the plant and returns it "level".

```
public static int findLevel(List<Plants> plants, int id) {
    if (plants == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("plants list must not be NULL");
    }
    Plants foundPlant = null;
    for (Plants plant: plants) {
        if (plant.getID() == id) {
            foundPlant = plant;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (foundPlant == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no such Plant with the given Id");
    }
    return foundPlant.getLevel();
}
```

With this method you can access the level of the list of plants and use it on your array.

```
for(int b=y1;b<=y2;b++) {
    tirednessMap[a][b]=tirednessMap[a][b]+findLevel(allPlants, aydiz[i]);
}
```

Keep in mind that you might need to adjust the method call depending on where you have your `findLevel()` method defined.

Comment: Since you know you want to lookup by `id`, wouldn't a `Map<Integer, Plants>` be a better solution, so you can simply do `map.get(id)`?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it would. As I said, this is one of many solutions. I didn't want to bring Maps inside this solution because I don't know if the OP knows/understands Maps, but maybe he knows/understands Lists/ArrayLists.

Comment: But, if OP doesn't know how to use a map this is a great time for him/her to learn. As a developer, if I want ids and values, then my immediate gut should be to use something mappy.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `HashMap`, where you map ids to `Plants`. Although you should probably rename `Plants` to `Plant` to avoid ambiguity if possible.

Example:

```
HashMap<Integer, Plants> plantMap = new HashMap<>();
plantMap.add(1, tomato);
//...etc.
```

To retrieve level of `tomato` simply call:

```
plantMap.get(1).getLevel();
```

Using a map ensures that you will never have two `Plants` objects that share an id, as well as greatly decrease time taken for lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Same findLevel method suggested by Progman using streams:

```
public static int findLevel(List<Plants> plants, int id) {
    if (plants == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("plants list must not be NULL");
    }
    Optional<Integer> foundPlantLevel = plants.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getID() == id)
            .map(p -> p.getLevel())
            .findAny();
    return foundPlantLevel.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("There is no such Plant with the given Id"));
}
```

Anyway, I would use a Map structure to access Plant objects directly by their ids.